# How do I restore a MSSQL .bak file onto PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, restore

Just as the title says :) I have a MSSQL `something.bak` file and I would like to import that `db` into PostgreSQL

Comment: Simply answer: you can not. You need to restore it into a running SQL Server, then export the data from there e.g. into CSV files and import those into Postgres.

Comment: Is `export into CSV` something you can do on the entire db? Like how you would backup the db normally. In other words, is it easy?

Comment: That depends on the tools you are using some make that easy some don't. I don't use SQL Server so I don't know what options you have there. Or you can use something like this: https://github.com/mzarnitsa/mssql2pg

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the flat files stage is actually optional. You can pump the data with SSIS, or via a linked server (not sure if PG has something like it though).

Comment: Do you want to import just the data, or the entire database (data, table & column definitions, indexes, other and more obscure database objects?)

Answer (score 2):

you can not restore backup file in postgress.you have use SSIS package to copy data from mssql to mssql.